# Ubuntu always asks for RSA certificate passphrase with ftpserver installed

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ubuntu-server, rsa, proftpd

I am trying to learn how to use Linux servers. I have installed Ubuntu Server 12.04. I have `apache2`, `mysql`, and `proftpd` installed.

For `proftpd` I created authentication via TLS. I had to generate a certificate with a passphrase. (I followed a tutorial on the Ubuntu Forums but forgot the link)

Whenever I start the server, before fully booting to the login screen, **it prompts me for the RSA certificate passphrase**. The only problem is, 4 out of 5 times it won't let me actually input anything and just hangs there sayings incorrect passphrase once.

If I reboot the server a couple times while randomly pressing buttons, sometimes it will let me enter the passphrase but will not accept it. So if I just keep hitting enter at this point, after about 4 or 5 "incorrect passphrase" messages it finally just gives up and presents the login screen finally.

Any ideas why this is happening? I'd rather not just remove the passphrase and do not know enough yet about server administration and the like to really know whats going on here.